# How can I keep a set of objects in Perl?

Tags: perl, data-structures, reference, set

I would like to keep a set of (Moose) objects, so each object could only appear once.

I thought of using a hash where the key is the address of the object then check for existence of the key before I add an object. Is that a common practice? How do I get the address of the object?

**UPDATE**

On second thought, what's wrong with simply using the object reference as the key:

```
my %objects = ();

# some object (just created or or taken from somewhere...)
my $object ...

# add object to set
$objects{$object} = $object;

# operate on all objects
foreach my $obj (values %objects) {
...
}
```

Comment: David - to clarify, do you want to enforce "only one of each object per class" or simply "each specific object instance only added once, but multiple different objects of the same class are perfectly fine"?

Comment: Hash keys are always strings. Therefore, when you use a reference as a hash key, it is stringified. If the stringification is overloaded, then you might end up with different objects mapping to the same string.

Comment: In addition to Sinan's caveat, using a stringified reference as a key (or `refaddr`, for that matter) won't survive a serialization cycle. Thawed objects won't be allocated at the same address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Set::Object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Set%3a%3aObject).

To get the address of a reference, you can use [Scalar::Util::refaddr](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Scalar%3a%3aUtil).

Comment: I may be mis-understanding the question, but the context I got was that there should be only 1 of each type of object, e.g. they should be Singletons. Set::Object doesn't seem to help with that. I asked OP to clarify

Comment: @DVK I took *"so each object could only appear once"* to correspond to the mathematical definition of a set (as opposed to a *tuple*).

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE** This answer only applies if you want to keep one object **per class** - if the OP meant "one unique object instance but multiple instances per class", this answer is wrong and Sinan's should be used.

A common pattern to implement such an approach (called a Singleton), is to implement a factory method for creating such objects and a storage for keeping them.

So, you would have:

- A package containing the factory and the object set
- That package has a hash, with key being the **type** of object (you can use class name as a type) and the value being the object of that type.
- A factory method make_object, which is provided as one of the arguments with the **type** of object to make
- An accessor returning an object of a specific type (basically a lookup in the hash mentioned above)
- Optionally, a "retrieve-or-create" method whith the logic of `if (!exists_object($type)) { make_object($type); return get_object($type) }`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a domain key that can be expressed as a scalar, you can just use a regular hash.

A) You have cars identified by VIN-1 and VIN-2 and VIN-3. Those can be keys to a hash.

B) You have cars identified by type, 'sedan', 'SUV', 'pick-up'. But you can have multiple, different sedans. Essentially, there is no domain key besides the unique existence of an object. This cannot be done with a hash (unless as you mentioned you try using the address of the reference, not sure how good of a practice that is though).

Answer (score 1):

I'd just add [MooseX::Singleton](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/MooseX-Singleton-0.25/lib/MooseX/Singleton.pm) to the list of singleton solutions already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest bit of code would be:

```
our $SINGLETON;
sub new {
    return $SINGLETON if $SINGLETON;
    # .... normal object creation
    $SINGLETON = $self;
    return $self;
}
```